# Prepared statement PDO does nothing

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to figure out how prepared statements work in PDO. I have the following file:

```
<?php


$user = "root";
$pass = "<removed for this post>";
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=pdo-demo", $user, $pass);

$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO pdo-demo (firstname, lastname, email) value (:firstname, :lastname, :email)");

$stmt->bindParam(':firstname', $firstname);
$stmt->bindParam(':lastname', $lastname);
$stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);

$firstname = "John";
$lastname = "Doe";
$email = "johndoe@nowhere123.com";
$stmt->execute();

$db = null;?>
```

When I enter the page nothing happens, what am I missing? Shouldn't it insert the data?

Comment: `pdo-demo` that translates to `pdo minus demo`.

Comment: You are missing error reporting. Refer to the linked answer for the proper setup to get the error message from PHP.PDO which will give you a clue.

Comment: This question was closed with the wrong duplicate in not addressing the real problem. Simply getting errors doesn't inform what the person should have used. Get that through your head YCS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql)

Comment: to which I reopened with this ^ new duplicate. So, wrap it in ticks `\`` or use an underscore.

Comment: it worked, @Fred-ii- , will post answer

Comment: why is my post downvoted?

Comment: @crystyxn well one person obviously used my comment in their answer *lol*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I needed backticks (`) for the variable names like so:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `pdo-demo` (`firstname`, `lastname`, `email`) value (:firstname, :lastname, :email)");
```

Now it worked

Answer (score 0):

pdo-demo that translates to pdo minus demo And your using that name for database AND table.

Comment: both my db and table are called pdo-demo

Comment: [*"pdo-demo that translates to pdo minus demo"*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42469803/prepared-statement-pdo-does-nothing?noredirect=1#comment72080427_42469803) - If you're going to post an answer based on a comment, you really should be quoting the person who wrote that comment up there, mainly *"moi"*.

Comment: My bad, won't happen again